# Tools to perform performance testing on Desktop?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Please share- open source tools available to execute performance testing on desktop application

Currently we are using Apache Jmeter for Web applications, however not sure which tool can be used for Desktop apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desktop application is using [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols you can use JMeter just the same way you're using it for web applications, to wit:

1. Record your desktop application traffic using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Perform correlation and parameterization if required
3. Replay recorded script with [increased number of threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)

See [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more information on configuring JMeter and the desktop app for recording.

Also be aware that using JMeter you can only load test the **backend**, to wit simulate hundreds of desktop apps simultaneously sending queries to the backend server(s). If you want to assess the performance of the desktop application itself - you should go for application [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming) instead, it will give you an overview of resources consumed by application, heaviest functions, largest objects, slowest parts, etc.